# Does "Unlocking the Sharpshooter" affect assault rifles?

Tags: payday-2

The "Unlocking the Sharpshooter" "ACE" improves all rifles, so does that means also the assault rifles?

Comment: What is the **exact** wording?  The details are in the wording.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description, the ace version of the Technician class's "Unlocking the Sharpshooter" skill, increases weapon stability when using any rifle. The effect of getting this skill increases the mobility of all assault rifles by 25%. However, the only rifles you can get in this game are assault rifles. So as such, this skill only applies to them.

Comment: What sniper rifles? Not aware there are any in the game.

Comment: Isn't the M308 considered to be a sniper rifle? Or am I confusing this for something else? If you confirm that there are no sniper rifles, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well the M308 is a semi-automatic rifle for range, so I guess, but it's just semantics really. It's not a Barrett M82 or anything! ;)
User wiki, http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons_(Payday_2)

Comment: Shoot, I misinterpreted what the game and wiki said. Editing my answer. Thanks for the clarification David.